# Sending a patch request to edit video using vimeo api not working

Tags: ruby, http, vimeo-api

I am trying to send a patch request to edit a video using vimeo api using ruby. The request is successful but vimeo is not able to read my the payload(the title and description), that is, the the title and the description is not getting changed. I have used HTTParty, RestClient as well as Net::HTTP but none of it works. Below are my code that i have implemented to send a patch request,

**RestClient**

```
payload = {"description" => "Test Description", "name" => "Test Video"}
res = RestClient.patch(
             vimeo_edit_url, 
             payload.to_s,
             { "Authorization" => auth })
```

**NET::HTTP**

```
options = {'description' => "Test Description", 'name' => "Test Video"}
edit_req = Net::HTTP::Patch.new(vimeo_edit_url, initheader = { "Authorization" => auth})
edit_req.data = options.to_s
edit_uri = URI(vimeo_edit_url)
edit_http = Net::HTTP.new(edit_uri.host, edit_uri.port)
edit_http.use_ssl = true
edit_http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
edit_response = edit_http.request(edit_req)
```

Usually the response will be a 200 OK with the updated video details but I get a 200 OK with video details(title and description not being changed). It is as if like vimeo is not able to read my payload.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to be passing `payload`, not `payload.to_s`.

That `.to_s` is turning your nicely arranged hash into a weird rubyified string, and all of the HTTP libraries you mentioned will accept a hash and handle the conversion for you.

Here's what some different representations look like in an `irb` session:

```
>> payload = {"description" => "Test Description", "name" => "Test Video"}
>> payload
=> {"description"=>"Test Description", "name"=>"Test Video"}
>> payload.to_s
=> "{"description"=>"Test Description", "name"=>"Test Video"}"
>> require 'json'
=> true
>> payload.to_json
=> "{"description":"Test Description","name":"Test Video"}"
```